# Compute the Optimal Square Matrix

Tags: code-golf, array, integer, matrix

The **optimal matrix** (for the rather narrow scope of this challenge) is obtained by "zipping" the elements from the corresponding rows and columns of a square matrix and getting the maximum of each pair.

For instance, given the following matrix:

```
4 5 6
1 7 2
7 3 0
```

You can combine it with its transpose to get: `[[[4,5,6],[4,1,7]],[[1,7,2],[5,7,3]],[[7,3,0],[6,2,0]]]`. If you zip each pair of lists, you obtain the following: `[[(4,4),(5,1),(6,7)],[(1,5),(7,7),(2,3)],[(7,6),(3,2),(0,0)]]`. The last step is to get the maximum of each pair to get the optimal matrix:

```
4 5 7
5 7 3
7 3 0
```

Your task is to output the optimal matrix of a square matrix given as input. The matrix will only contain integers. I/O can be done in any reasonable format. The shortest code in bytes (either in UTF-8 or in the language's custom encoding) wins!

#### Tests

```
[[172,29],[29,0]] -> [[172,29],[29,0]]
[[4,5,6],[1,7,2],[7,3,0]] -> [[4,5,7],[5,7,3],[7,3,0]]
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] -> [[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[3,3,3]]
[[4,5,-6],[0,8,-12],[-2,2,4]] -> [[4,5,-2],[5,8,2],[-2,2,4]]
```

Comment: Can we output a flat version of the matrix? e.g. `[1,2,3,4]` instead of `[[1,2],[3,4]]`? Would save ~33%

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
»Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q7qj/h9sfNa1xB@KsRw1zDm07tO3//@joaENzIx0FI8tYHS4FhWggQ0dBwSAWyONSiI420VEw1VEwg8gZ6iiYA1VCOECWsQ5CIVAOaIoxVKGCDhIHKgNVqAAxUkEXaqiCgY6ChY6CriHUXF0jsHoFBZPY2FgA)

#### How it works

```
»Z  Main link. Argument: M (integer matrix)

 Z  Zip the rows of M, transposing rows and columns.
»   Take the maxima of all corresponding integers.
```

Comment: Oh my... Why in the world does `»` behave like that?!

Comment: Pretty standard for an array manipulation language. Octave's `max` does the same.

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

Whoop, never got to use `‡` before (or `†`):

```
S‡▲T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/hRw8JH0zaF/P//PzraRMdUR9csVifaQMdCR9fQCMjSNdIx0jGJjQUA)

#### Explanation

```
S  T -- apply the function to itself and itself transposed
 ‡▲  -- bi-vectorized maximum
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 40 bytes

```hs
z(z max)<*>foldr(z(:))e
e=[]:e
z=zipWith
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzv0qjSiE3sULTRssuLT8npUijSsNKUzOVK9U2OtYqlavKtiqzIDyzJON/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmkJ0tImOqY5ZrE60oY65jhGQNtcx1jGIjf3/LzktJzG9@L9uckEBAA)

I would ungolf this as:

```hs
import Data.List
f m = zipWith (zipWith max) m (transpose m)
```

...which is so much more elegant.

Comment: I find it funny that the best I could golf in Clean is identical to your ungolfed Haskell.

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 13 bytes

```
@(A)max(A,A')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQcNRMzexQsNRx1Fd83@agq1CYl6xNRdXmka0obmRgpGlNRArGMRqgkRMFEwVzKwVDBXMFYysgYQxTMJQwUjBGCSBoBA6dIFaDBQsFHQNgZp0gWYqmMRq/gcA)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
t!2$X>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v0TRSCXC7v//aBMFUwUzawVDBXMFI2sgYaxgEAsA)

**Explanation:**

```
t        % Duplicate the input.
!        % Transpose the duplicate.
2$X>     % Elementwise maximum of the two matrices.
```

Comment: Also 6 bytes: `_t!Xl_` and `tt!&Xl`.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
⊢⌈⍉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXYse9XQ86u0EchWMFYwf9W4xUTBVMFMwVDBXMAJiYwUDrjSFR20TH/VN9Qr291NQj442NDfSMbKM1Yk2stQxiI1Vx1BgomOqYwaUN9Qx1zEC0uY6xtgVGuoY6RiDFSLTOEzUBRlpoGOho2sIMlQX6AgdE6BiAA)

`⊢` argument

`⌈` ceiling'd with

`⍉` transposed argument

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

```js
m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>v>(k=m[x][y])?v:k))
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>v>(k=m[x][y])?v:k))

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([[172,29],[29,0]]            ))) // -> [[172,29],[29,0]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([[4,5,6],[1,7,2],[7,3,0]]    ))) // -> [[4,5,7],[5,7,3],[7,3,0]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]    ))) // -> [[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[3,3,3]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([[4,5,-6],[0,8,-12],[-2,2,4]]))) // -> [[4,5,-2],[5,8,2],[-2,2,4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>12</s> <s>10</s> 8 bytes

Look, Ma, no transposing or zipping!

```
£XËwUgEY
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=o1jLd1VnRVk=&input=W1s0LDUsLTZdLFswLDgsLTEyXSxbLTIsMiw0XV0KLVE=)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 4 bytes

Tacit prefix function.

```
>.|:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83Wyk6vxup/anJGvkKagrGCsYqJgqmCmYKhgrmCERAbKxhwQSWNFIxUDM2BpCUIwYXx6gFJGgIFjRWQSHSd8WYKBgoWCvGGRgrxQOMVTP4DAA)

`>.` ceiling [of the argument] with

`|:` the transposed argument

Comment: Um, I don't think you need to include `f=:`. :P at first I thought you reduced the bytecount by 3 bytes...

Comment: `<.` is supposed to be `>.`

Comment: @FrownyFrog Indeed.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No, I don't.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 23 bytes

```r
function(A)pmax(A,t(A))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmD7P600L7kkMz9Pw1GzIDexQsNRpwTI1PyfppGSmZiuYQJkAgA)

This is equivalent to most other answers. However, R has two distinct `max` functions for the two common scenarios:

> `max` and `min` return the maximum or minimum of all the values present in their arguments, as integer if all are logical or integer, as double if all are numeric, and character otherwise.
>
> `pmax` and `pmin` take one or more vectors (or matrices) as arguments and return a single vector giving the ‘parallel’ maxima (or minima) of the vectors. The first element of the result is the maximum (minimum) of the first elements of all the arguments, the second element of the result is the maximum (minimum) of the second elements of all the arguments and so on. Shorter inputs (of non-zero length) are recycled if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
{_z..e>}
```

Anonymous block (function) that takes the input from the stack and replaces it by the output.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/Or5KTy/VrvZ/XcH/6GgTBVMFs1iFaEMFcwUjIG2uYKxgEBsLAA) Or [**verify all test cases**](https://tio.run/##TYxBCoAgFAWv8jYtFf1a1qaLyCci2gRBbRO9umkUtJoHw7xlm/d8ppDDdEm5jjGnIzbZe@0INDA8DVBc6C1adGVoOFChg3mNBsE85s@vETVS6CF0zUT5hWXmGw).

#### Explanation

```
{      }    e# Define block
 _          e# Duplicate
  z         e# Zip
   .        e# Apply next operator to the two arrays, item by item
            e# (that is, to rows of the two matrices)
    .       e# Apply next operator to the two arrays, item by item
            e# (that is, to numbers of the two rows)
     e>     e# Maximum of two numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>79</s> 77 bytes

- Saved two bytes thanks to [Steadybox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61405/steadybox); only taking in one matrix dimension parameter as all matrices in this challenge are square.

```c
j,i;f(A,n)int*A;{for(j=0;j<n*n;j++)printf("%d,",A[A[j]>A[i=j/n+j%n*n]?j:i]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7RCoIwGAXga3uKEIItj6SztFoWsx4iEC/CMDZoRdmV@Ow2lago2Haz75z/z91TnjeNguQFEdBU6nIseFVcbkTFHlcrPdZcOQ693sxXQezRETZEKlKVrUUqYzXRjhoZlW3UUmaU1835IDWh1cAaWCYzFGkWV37EwBbt8epuFKP8@ijvxLYp713SuilmCOEjAjM36HWC4Edvu1ajAny8rd7@0btXtxvCwxyuz@CajTBtE7s/if27vzP7743r5gk)

Takes a flat integer array `A` and the matrix dimension `n` (as the matrix has to be square) as input. Outputs a flat integer array string representation to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 58 bytes

```
import StdEnv,StdLib
@l=zipWith(zipWith max)(transpose l)l
```

I don't think this needs an explanation.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r0wHSPlkJnE55NhWZRaEZ5ZkaEBpoOIKTY2SosS84oL84lSFHM2c/8EliUCdtgoOCtHRJjqmOrpmsTrRBjoWOrqGRkCWrpGOkY5JbOz/f8lpOYnpxf91PX3@u1TmJeZmJkM4ENsA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 23 bytes

A port of my [Pari/GP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152474/9288).

```
(#+#+Abs[#-#])/2&
```

`` is [`\[Transpose]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Transpose.html).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/BfQ1lb@X1/u7ZjUnG0si6IGaupb6T2P6AoM68kOi26utpEx1THrFan2lDHXMcISJvrGOsY1NbGxv4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 13 bytes

`max.` applies the function `max` elementwise to it's arugments.

```julia
a->max.(a,a')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@5@mYKuQlJqemfc/UdcuN7FCTyNRJ1Fd839qXgpXSmZxQU5ipUaaRrSJgqmCmbWhgrmCkbW5grGCQaym5n8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 45 bytes

```python
lambda k:[map(max,*c)for c in zip(k,zip(*k))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDLboMwEEX3/oqpu8HpECUmDQkSi35BN91RFpSYQnkY2U5fP09tlyhZRKq68chzfebO9fhlajnwqUqfp67oXw4FtEnWF2PQF5@4KFklFZTQDPDdjEGL7ly0jOWTEdpoSCHLsg3e4zbHbI0xcltjjHCV52i1NXKMvHRZveSo0GEr3GG4dmDIrbyZydhe9rbJ925YTrTsjqaRw4VpbGV7@slXTPlcIytdmnKP7fBPS@LSu6AIJ/fTV/j457ZmCYFRNYMB@lQLUEIfOwONpgi0lEqJ0iQUmgoqjzJI0/NM0WkB9EPJ4TWhqI0K5ldsqd6O2gTRlt3RJSXkFh4HAb1UAspalG0C/12y0Fooc20NQnwAMsd46LpfDw118S5gdOThhk4/)

Thanks to totallyhuman for a few bytes saved.

Comment: [45 bytes.](https://tio.run/##lZDLboMwEEX3/oqpu8HpECUmDQkSi35BN91RFpSYQnkY2U5fP09tlyhZRKq68chzfebO9fhlajnwqUqfp67oXw4FtEnWF2PQF5@4KFklFZTQDPDdjEGL7ly0jOWTEdpoSCHLsg3e4zbHbI0xcltjjHCV52i1NXKMvHRZveSo0GEr3GG4dmDIrbyZydhe9rbJ925YTrTsjqaRw4VpbGV7@slXTPlcIytdmnKP7fBPS@LSu6AIJ/fTV/j457ZmCYFRNYMB@lQLUEIfOwONpgi0lEqJ0iQUmgoqjzJI0/NM0WkB9EPJ4TWhqI0K5ldsqd6O2gTRlt3RJSXkFh4HAb1UAspalG0C/12y0Fooc20NQnwAMsd46LpfDw118S5gdOThhk4/ "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
ø‚øεøεà
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8I5HDbMO7zi3FYwX/P8fHW2iY6qjaxarE22gY6Gja2gEZOka6RjpmMTGAgA)

**Explanation**

```
ø         # transpose input matrix
 ‚        # pair with original matrix
  ø       # zip together
   ε      # apply on each sublist ([[row],[transposed row]])
    ø     # zip
     ε    # apply on each sublist (pair of elements)
      à   # extract greatest element
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
żZZṀ€$€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///onqiohzsbHjWtUQHi////R0eb6JjqmMXqRBvqmOsYAWlzHWMdg9hYAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech.*

```
Map@Max/@t/@t@{#,t@#}&
t=#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zexwME3sULfoQSIHKqVdUoclGvVuEpsld/3t6v9DyjKzCuJTlNwUKiuNtEx1TGr1ak21DHXMQLS5jrGOga1tbH/AQ)

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zexICSjKDUxJdo3saIOzqurVlauVdOpVtZRft/fXhur9j@gKDOvJDpNwUGhutpEx1THrFan2lDHXMcISJvrGOsY1NbG/gcA); using Mathematica's [transpose operator](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html).

Comment: How would you implement this in an Mathematica notebook using, say, the 2nd test case (`{{4,5,6},{1,7,2},{7,3,0}}`)?

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 21 bytes

```
m->(m+m~+abs(m-m~))/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9X104jVzu3TjsxqVgjVze3TlNT3@h/QVFmXolGmka0iY6pjpm1oY65jpG1uY6xjkGspuZ/AA)